# Django: Display existing image with an instantiated ModelForm, rather than a file input?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-models

I have some images assigned to an ImageField on several saved model instances. I want to display a ModelForm based on the model of interest, only for the purpose of setting one foreign key on the model. I'm instantiating the ModelForm with the model I want to edit.

All I'd like to do is display the existing image for the model along with the FK select. It would be easy enough to do both separately, but as I am actually displaying multiple forms side by side, within a `{% for form in forms %}` loop, I want to get the image displayed using something along the lines of `<img src="{{ form.image.get_image_url }} />`. I don't believe any template syntax like this exists for ImageField's on forms, but hopefully you catch my drift.

This seems like it should be a trivial exercise, but I haven't found a clear answer in the documentation or elsewhere. There was a suggestion on some forum threads that creating a custom field Widget might be the recommended solution, mostly with regards to customizing the admin, but I can't sort out the details of exactly how I should do this in my case on the site front-end. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the model object associated with a ModelForm (provided such an association exists) using `form.instance`. From there you can access the image as you normally do.

Comment: That's perfect, just the kind of 'duh' solution I was hoping for and even expecting. Thank you very much JaC.